# How To show category Values in Different ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, instance, categories

I am having Baseclass `Connections` and  Category `CoreDataProperties`.In my “FirstViewController” am Storing data to `CoreDataProperties` attributes and i can also able to show the data using the instance of `Connections` class.My problem is, i want to access the stored values in my `SecondViewController`.if i create a Object for `Connections` and access means,it shows `null`.

Connections+CoreDataProperties.h

```
@interface EY_Connections (CoreDataProperties)
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *connectionAddress;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *connectionStatus;
@end
```

Firstviewcontroller.m

```
Connections *connect;
NSLog(@"ConnectionNo correct==>>%@",connect.connectionStatus);
```

It shows ConnectionStatus Value.But if I Do this in `SecondviewController`. Its Not showing.

SecondViewController.m

```
Connections *conn;
NSLog(@"er==>%@",conn.connectionStatus);
```

What is the Problem?How to show the stored Category values in SecondViewController?

Comment: Where is the property "connectionStatus" ? Please clarify with superclass

Comment: You are instantiating Connections in Firstviewcontroller.m right ? You need to instantiate it or pass it from previous viewcontroller .

Comment: If i instantiate in appDelegate means also,i am not able to access the Object....